# Extracting second list from nested list returned by XHR request

Tags: python, xmlhttprequest, python-requests

I am using the below code to return data from a website by copying an XHR request that is submitted to it:

```
import requests

url = 'http://www.whoscored.com/stageplayerstatfeed/-1/Overall'
params = {
'field': '0',
'isAscending': 'false',
'isMoreThanAvgApps': 'true',
'isOverall': 'false',
'numberOfPlayersToPick': '20',
'orderBy': 'Rating',
'page': '1',
'stageId': '9155',
'teamId': '-1'
}

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/36.0.1985.125 Safari/537.36',
           'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
           'Host': 'www.whoscored.com',
           'Referer': 'http://www.whoscored.com/'}

responser = requests.get(url, params=params, headers=headers)


responser = responser.text
responser = responser.encode('cp1252')
print responser
```

This returns a set of nested list. The first list is a simple list, whilst the second is a list of dictionaries. I want to return the second list.

I have tried amending the last line of my code to `print responser[1]`, however for some reason this just prints a `[`.

Can anyone see why this is not returning what I require?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`responser` variable contains a JSON string. That means that when you are getting `responser[1]`, you basically get the second character from the string, which is `[`.

Load the JSON string it into a python list. The easiest way is to use [`.json()`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/api/?highlight=json#requests.Response.json) method that `requests` module provides:

```
responser = requests.get(url, params=params, headers=headers)
data = responser.json()
print data[1]
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you're turning the request response into text. So this line:

```
responser = responser.text
```

should be:

```
responser = responser.json()
```

And then you can print:

```
print responser[1]
```